# Not found page when clicked detail to get data based on id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have been fixing this trivial problem a few days, but it didn't solve either.
When I click the detail button on the table, it will display a 404 or not found message.

**Controller method**

```
 public function detail($id)
    {
      $data = DB::table('lirik_lagu')->where('id', $id)->first();

      return view ('admin.detail-lirik');
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('lirik-lagu/detail/{$id}', [LirikLaguController::class, 'detail']);
```

**Blade**

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{{ url('admin/lirik-lagu/detail', $data->id) }}">Detail</a>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is the URL generated properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to fix what i think it's wrong in your code.
First you should give the `$data` to your blade file

**Controller method**

```
 public function detail($id)
        {
          $data = DB::table('lirik_lagu')->where('id', $id)->first();
    
          return view ('admin.detail-lirik',['data'=>$data]);
        }
```

Second, your should omit the `$` in your Route `id` parameters
**Route**

```
Route::get('lirik-lagu/detail/{id}', [LirikLaguController::class, 'detail']);
```

Third, when you generate the url `url(...)` it seems to have an `admin` prefix but not your route declaration.
**Blade**

```
  <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{{ url('lirik-lagu/detail', $data->id) }}">Detail</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the variable to the view. This is how you do it:

```
return view('admin.detail-lirik', $data);
```

If you need to pass multiple variables you can pass an array in the second paramter like this:

```
return view('admin.detail-lirik, ["varname" => $var]);
```

Comment: I have sent the data to the view

Comment: but still not found page

Comment: I showed this in my second example. Here the second parameter in the view function decides what variables to pass. In your case its passing along the $datas variables as $datas to the view (blade file)

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems here, so I'm going to point them out. First one, you never returned the data to your view:

```
return view ('admin.detail-lirik', $data);
```

The other is the URL in your blade file. You called `admin/lirik-lagu/detail` but you defined route without `admin` in your `web.php` file. You can remove the admin from your url, or create a name for your route and call it that way:

```
Route::get('lirik-lagu/detail/{$id}', [LirikLaguController::class, 'detail'])->name('lirik-langu');
```

And then use it like this

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{{ route('lirik-langu', $data->id) }}">Detail</a>
```